# QApplication app(argc, argv)

Tags: c++, qt, program-entry-point, argv, argc

I noticed that the `main.cpp` in a `Qt` application has to contain the following line:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
```

I know that `argc` is the number of command-line arguments, and `argv` is that array list of command-line arguments. But, the question in my mind is: **what are those arguments I'm passing to the constructor and at the same time cannot explicitly see? What is working behind the scences out there?**

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean when you say you cannot explicitly see them?

Comment: Why would it see? Those are parameters for the programs, you could give them any name, you could even emit them. How it should possibly see if you don't pass it forward. Those aren't global parameters but local ones (just like any attributes of a function).

Comment: I mean what are we passing? What are the arguments we are passing and their numbers?

Answer (score 2):

There are no hidden arguments. You can explicitly see every argument- `argc, argv`. There's nothing in that line of code that's behind the scenes.

Comment: I mean what are we passing? What are the arguments we are passing and their numbers?

Comment: @user714961: The values of argc and argv are determined at run-time, we couldn't possibly know what's in them. Conceptually, they are the command line arguments.

Answer (score 2):

Qt applications supports some command line arguments. For example `app.exe -style motif` on Windows is funny. Basically, in this constructor, you pass the arguments to the QApplication class in order they to be parsed.

And of course you are free to pass nothing to QApplication, like this:

`int c=1; char** v = &argv[0]; QApplication app(c,v);` so Qt won't parse anything and won't accept any command line arguments.

About argc and argv scope, if you pass then to QApplication you can access them from every point you want. If you don't pass them to QApplication, you have to take care yourself making them global.

Comment: The docs for 4.7 clearly state that `argc` must not be zero and `argv` must contain at least one character string.

Comment: Yes, i noted that they updated it. In real life, argv(0) is always defined. so you can do stuff like:

`int c=1; char** v = &argv[0]; QApplication app(c,v);`

Answer (score 2):

From looking at your comments to other answers, I think you are wondering about arguments passed in to your executable if you don't specify any arguments. I'm not sure if it is standardized or what the exceptions may be, but usually in this case, `argc` will be `1` and `argv[0]` will be a string that specifies the command that was used to invoke your executable.

Let's assume your executable is called `app` and resides in `/home/user/appdir`.

If your current directory is the applications directory and you launch it with 'app' then `argc` will be `1` and `argv[0]` will be `app`.

If you are one directory up from the application's directory and invoke it with `./appdir/app` then `argc` will be `1` and I believe `argv[0]` will be `appdir/app`

If you do specify an argument when invoking your application; perhaps you want to tell your application to output debug information like so `app debug`. In this case, `argc` will be `2`, `argv[0]` will be `app` and `argv[1]` will be `debug`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking what `QApplication` does with arguments then the answer is [in the docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qapplication.html). That page lists the arguments recognised by Qt.