# Qt , how to create QApplication without argc and argv

Tags: c++, qt, qapplication

Hey so I need to export a qt application as a .dll and , so I dont want any arguments like `argc` and `argv` , but `QApplication` needs them , so i tried this

```cpp
int main()
{
    int c=1;
    char** v = (char**)("ApplicationName");
    QApplication app(c,v);
    MainWindow window;
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```

but I get segfault from `QtCore`... Can someone help me bypass the segfault and create the `QApplication` without needing `argc` and `argv`?
This didnt solve the problem cause it needs argv defined ...
[QApplication app(argc, argv)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5770154/qapplication-appargc-argv)

Comment: By convention, `argv` should start with the name of the program (at position 0).

Comment: How could that work for a .dll?

Comment: `char** v` should be `char* v[]`, i.e. `v` should point a pointer, but you forced it to point a char.

Comment: @273K can you provide the whole expression? like how the cast should work? is it like this int c=1; char* []v = (char*[])("ApplicationName"); QApplication app(c,v);?

Comment: `const char* v[] = { "ApplicationName" };` Use the type cast later.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it! `int c=1; char* v[] = {(char*)"ApplicationName"}; QApplication app(c,v);`

Comment: Avoid C-style casts. They have too many possible meanings which is the issue here: You're basically `reinterpret_cast`ing from `char const*` to `char**`. Use `char* argv[1] { const_cast<char*>("ApplicationName")};` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```cpp
int main()
{
    char* args[] = { (char*)"AppName" };
    QApplication app(1,args);
    MainWindow window;
    window.show();
    return app.exec();
}
```